# Nginx: Buffer Chain

Tags: nginx

Was reading nginx guide by [Evan Millers](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html). Have difficulty in understanding the buffer chains.

> Why does the buffer have the last_buf variable, when we can tell we're at the end of a chain by checking "next" for NULL?
>
> Answer: A chain might be incomplete, i.e., have multiple buffers, but not all the buffers in this request or response. So some buffers are at the end of the chain but not the end of a request. This brings us to…

Can someone shed light on this topic overall? Or point to some guide that explains this?

Answer (score 2):

`last_buf` means the last buffer of the response body, while `next == NULL` just the last buffer in current chain that was passed to filter, it doesn't necessary contain the whole body.